# How to set gameobject to false in foreach loop in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

How to set active to false when in a foreach loop.
Here is the loop:

```
public void OnemoreTry(){
        var respawns = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Enemy");
        foreach (GameObject respawn in respawns) {
            respawn.SetActive(false);
        }
```

**ERROR:** foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type `UnityEngine.GameObject' because it does not contain a definition for`GetEnumerator' or is inaccessible

Comment: is `respawn.SetActive(false)` not working ? What is the error ?

Comment: foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type `UnityEngine.GameObject' because it does not contain a definition for `GetEnumerator' or is inaccessible

Comment: `FindGameObjectWithTag` only returns a single GameObject, not a collection of them. You should use the plural version `FindGameObjectsWithTag`.

Comment: @Cuderman looks like `respawn.SetActive(false)` works. It's just you're not using the plural version. Change to `var respawns = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Enemy");`

Comment: yes it works thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try FindGameObject**s**WithTag instead to get all tagged objects in an array instead of just the first object in the scene hierarchy.